# Is the Git "smart" remote protocol documented anywhere?

Tags: git, git-remote

I've found a number of pages purporting to be documentation of the version 1 & 2 protocols, ([link](https://git-scm.com/docs/http-protocol), [link](https://git-scm.com/docs/protocol-v2), etc.) but none of them include enough details to actually implement a client (for example, they don't mention if https request should be GET or POST nor include examples of more or less any non-trivial usage).

Does anyone know of better documentation? Something targeted at developers?

---

### Background:

Given a remote URL, I need to

1. find `HEAD`
2. find the latest "shallow-since" timestamp that will work with that `HEAD`.

And I need to do this from a process that don't have access to a file system it can write to (so it's not possible to do even a `--depth=1` clone).

Comment: The smart protocol is independent of the transport used: it's the same over ssh as over http or https. It just needs something that will do a two-way byte stream. The http/https wrapper is not interesting here (although of course it *is* interesting if you're writing something that uses the wrapper!).

Comment: Well, I'm using http as the transport so I think it's interesting here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only completely accurate response would be "use the source, Luke!", although I have to object to your

> for example, they don't mention if https request should be GET or POST

given

```
HTTP Transport
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

When using the http:// or https:// transport a client makes a "smart"
info/refs request as described in `http-protocol.txt` and requests that
v2 be used by supplying "version=2" in the `Git-Protocol` header.

   C: GET $GIT_URL/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.0
   C: Git-Protocol: version=2

A v2 server would reply:
```

and so forth right at the top of one of the links you say doesn't include this info, or am I mistaken somehow? I (re-)learn enough http to get by as needed, but that seems to be pretty darn clearly a `GET` request to me,

Comment: What I was hoping for is a listing of each thing that can be sent along with an example (e.g. a `curl` command) showing a valid URL, verb and body. Mixing the two docs, I think /info/refs us the *only* endpoint that GET is used on and the rest use POST... but that's just an educated guess.

Comment: A lot of servers don't speak the dumb http protocol any more, github at least tells you it doesn't.

Comment: That's why I'm asking about the smart protocol. It is in theory possible to talk the smart protocol via `curl` isn't it?

Comment: No. http is being used to run code (edit: to be pedantic, the webserver has to be set up to interpret the url that way, that's why it's the "smart" protocol, not the dumb one that interprets urls as a filesystem path), specifically the service named in the url, like `git-upload-pack`. That's a real program, supplied by git.

Comment: I was assuming that was the case. When I point curl at github, that program will run (on github's server) and return something I can read and process. -- To be clear, I'm trying to be the client here, not the server.

Comment: When you invoke a program via url the rest of the conversation doesn't have to be http. In fact, that's the entire point of invoking a separate program: to not be constrained by that protocol's limits any more. The docs you link give the sequence and syntax of the rest of the conversation. You can try e.g.  `GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 git clone --depth=1`, and likewise with pushes for the receive-pack sequence.

Comment: Do you have documentation that that is the case? Or are you assuming that? I ask because I've managed to do an `ls-refs` command as just an HTTP request, I've seen no indication of protocol switching (i.e. 101 status codes) while trying things and none of the docs taking about http seem to suggest that.

Comment: If you *do* know of documentation on that, I suspect that documentation is at least part of what I'm looking for.

Comment: receive-pack and upload-pack speak to whatever's connected to their standard i/o files, and they speak the pack protocol, documented in pack-protocol.txt,

Comment: reading between the lines, it seems that `receive-pack`/`upload-pack`'s standard input/output are plumbed to the HTTP request and response body. Assuming that, as long as I can avoid needing to do a back and forth I can just use it as a standard dynamic HTTP handler. But that's what I already knew when I started writing up this question.

Answer (score 1):

There are several documents in the `Documentation/technical` directory which, together, should enumerate the necessary pieces:

- `http-protocol.txt`
- `pack-protocol.txt`
- `protocol-capabilities.txt`
- `protocol-common.txt`
- `protocol-v2.txt`

Note that there are actually two different smart protocols, v0 and v2.  The latter should be common enough on most major hosting sites, but it isn't available everywhere.

You can see the data with `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` and a normal client.

As to the data you're looking for, you can find `HEAD` by making a normal ref request (e.g., `git ls-remote`), which will tell you the values of the symrefs.  The second part is non-trivial, because timestamps are only serialized in commits, and in order to get any commit data, you'll need to perform at least some sort of fetch or clone to get the commit objects.  You could do this into memory, but you'd probably want to try a library like libgit2 for that.

Comment: "Some sort of fetch or clone" is what I've been trying to figure out. But I'm hoping to figure out a way to do that that consume a minimum of network bandwidth, preferably a constant amount or at least less than `clone --depth=1` uses.  libgit2 might offer some help there, but given the CLI doesn't seem to provide what I want I suspect I'd need to call into the implementation details, which in my experience tend to be less stable than wire protocols.

Comment: You probably want a partial clone without any tree objects, but libgit2 doesn't support that.  You're going to need to either give up on not using local disk or not using a lot of bandwidth given existing implementations.  If you're always using a given server implementation (e.g. GitHub), you can use the API to fetch the latest commit timestamp, but if you need an implementation-agnostic solution, those are the limitations.

Comment: I wonder: if I can avoid the no-FS constraint, would `git init; git remote add $URL ; git something ...` without doing a `fetch` or `checkout` get me closer to what I want? Can Git be tricked into pulling down a single commit (presumably just the deltas) without the rest of the data that would be needed to actually check it out? -- I wonder if I could fabricate garbage under `./.git/` to make it *think* I already have everything else?

Comment: You can use a bare repository, but you will need to fetch or clone at least. You can do a shallow bare clone (`git clone --bare --depth 1`) and then find information about the commit if you want.

Comment: I don't think `--bare` provides any value I'm looking for. Also I'm thinking that to get what I want will have to use git in ways that it's not intended for, possiblity including modifications to the repo outside what the cli supports.

Comment: `--bare` prevents you from having to check out the repository, which will save you a bunch of disk space.  But what you're wanting to do is use the remote server as a generic repository contents API endpoint, which Git isn't designed for.  If you're working with a specific server, like GitHub, then they provide endpoints for that, but the Git protocol does not.

Comment: FWIW: if I can write *anything* at all to disk, then I don't need --bare. Disk capacity isn't the issue. -- To your other point, I long ago, before I posted this question, figured out that what I'm wanting isn't what it was designed for. Which is why I'm not asking how it intends to support my goal, but rather looking at abusing it into doing what I want.